# React Native Release( IPA and APK ) crash on start

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

Iam getting the below error when I open the release build .It happens both in IOS and Android.

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
Process: com.package.name, PID: 28695
com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: typeAnnotation, stack:
@980:17088
v@2:1473
@979:425
v@2:1473
@978:339
v@2:1473
@971:6338
v@2:1473
@970:139
v@2:1473
@969:218
v@2:1473
@968:117
v@2:1473
@882:1330
v@2:1473
@545:542
v@2:1473
@406:344
v@2:1473
@6:57
v@2:1473
d@2:875
global code@1766:3
at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:83)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:151)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Project Information

```
System:
OS: macOS 11.0.1
CPU: (16) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9880H CPU @ 2.30GHz
Memory: 111.48 MB / 16.00 GB
Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
 Binaries:
Node: 10.16.3 - /usr/local/bin/node
Yarn: 1.22.5 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
npm: 6.14.10 - /usr/local/bin/npm
Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
Managers:
CocoaPods: 1.9.3 - /usr/local/bin/pod
SDKs:
 iOS SDK:
  Platforms: iOS 14.2, DriverKit 20.0, macOS 11.0, tvOS 14.2, watchOS 7.1
 Android SDK:
   API Levels: 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29
  Build Tools: 19.1.0, 20.0.0, 21.1.2, 22.0.1, 23.0.1, 23.0.2, 23.0.3, 24.0.0, 24.0.1, 24.0.2, 24.0.3, 25.0.0, 25.0.1, 25.0.2, 25.0.3, 26.0.0, 26.0.1, 26.0.2, 26.0.3, 27.0.0, 27.0.1, 27.0.2, 27.0.3, 28.0.0, 28.0.1, 28.0.2, 28.0.3, 29.0.0, 29.0.1, 29.0.2, 29.0.3, 30.0.0, 30.0.3
  System Images: android-26 | Intel x86 Atom, android-26 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-26 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-27 | Intel x86 Atom, android-27 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-30 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom
  Android NDK: Not Found
IDEs:
Android Studio: 4.1 AI-201.8743.12.41.6953283
Xcode: 12.2/12B45b - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
Java: 1.8.0_221 - /usr/bin/javac
Python: 2.7.16 - /usr/bin/python
npmPackages:
@react-native-community/cli: Not Found
react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1 
react-native: ^0.63.3 => 0.63.4 
react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
*react-native*: Not Found
```

Package.json

```
  {
  "name": "AwrStarterKit",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "ios-build:dev": "gulp set --env=dev && react-native run-ios",
    "ios-build:test": "gulp set --env=test && react-native run-ios",
    "ios-build:prod": "gulp set --env=prod && react-native run-ios",
    "android-build:dev": "gulp set --env=dev && react-native run-android",
    "android-build:test": "gulp set --env=test && react-native run-android",
    "android-build:prod": "gulp set --env=test && react-native run-android",
    "android-releaseBuild:test": "gulp set --env=test && cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease",
    "android-releaseBuild:prod": "gulp set --env=test && cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew assembleRelease",
    "android-clean": "cd android && ./gradlew clean",
    "generate": "plop"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@notifee/react-native": "^0.13.2",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.0",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^5.9.7",
    "@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "^0.1.0-rc.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^7.6.7",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^8.4.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^8.4.9",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^7.8.11",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.9.0",
    "@react-navigation/compat": "^5.2.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.1",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "firebase": "^7.22.0",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^2.0.0",
    "i18n-js": "^3.7.1",
    "js-base64": "^3.5.2",
    "js-pascalcase": "^1.2.1",
    "lodash.memoize": "^4.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "plop": "^2.7.4",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "^0.63.3",
    "react-native-af-video-player": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-android-location-enabler": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-aws3": "^0.0.9",
    "react-native-calendar-events": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-camera": "^3.40.0",
    "react-native-config": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-dash": "^0.0.11",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-device-info": "^6.1.0",
    "react-native-event-listeners": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-exception-handler": "^2.10.8",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.3.3",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.16.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-highlight-words": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-hyperlink": "^0.0.19",
    "react-native-i18n": "^2.0.15",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.35.0",
    "react-native-image-gallery": "^2.1.5",
    "react-native-image-pan-zoom": "^2.1.12",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.4",
    "react-native-keep-awake": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-localize": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-map-link": "^2.7.19",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.27.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.6",
    "react-native-mov-to-mp4": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-orientation": "^3.1.3",
    "react-native-pdf": "^6.2.1",
    "react-native-permissions": "^2.2.2",
    "react-native-photo-view-ex": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-progress": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.2",
    "react-native-render-html": "^4.2.4",
    "react-native-restart": "^0.0.17",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.16.1",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-thumbnail": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-touch-id": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0",
    "react-native-version-number": "^0.3.6",
    "react-native-video": "^5.1.0-alpha8",
    "react-native-view-overflow": "^0.0.5",
    "react-native-webview": "^10.9.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.1",
    "react-navigation-transitions": "^1.0.12",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-promise-middleware": "^6.1.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "stacktrace-js": "^2.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "react-native": {
    "zlib": "browserify-zlib",
    "console": "console-browserify",
    "constants": "constants-browserify",
    "crypto": "react-native-crypto",
    "dns": "dns.js",
    "net": "react-native-tcp",
    "domain": "domain-browser",
    "http": "@tradle/react-native-http",
    "https": "https-browserify",
    "os": "react-native-os",
    "path": "path-browserify",
    "querystring": "querystring-es3",
    "fs": "react-native-level-fs",
    "_stream_transform": "readable-stream/transform",
    "_stream_readable": "readable-stream/readable",
    "_stream_writable": "readable-stream/writable",
    "_stream_duplex": "readable-stream/duplex",
    "_stream_passthrough": "readable-stream/passthrough",
    "dgram": "react-native-udp",
    "stream": "stream-browserify",
    "timers": "timers-browserify",
    "tty": "tty-browserify",
    "vm": "vm-browserify",
    "tls": false
  },
  "browser": {
    "zlib": "browserify-zlib",
    "console": "console-browserify",
    "constants": "constants-browserify",
    "crypto": "react-native-crypto",
    "dns": "dns.js",
    "net": "react-native-tcp",
    "domain": "domain-browser",
    "http": "@tradle/react-native-http",
    "https": "https-browserify",
    "os": "react-native-os",
    "path": "path-browserify",
    "querystring": "querystring-es3",
    "fs": "react-native-level-fs",
    "_stream_transform": "readable-stream/transform",
    "_stream_readable": "readable-stream/readable",
    "_stream_writable": "readable-stream/writable",
    "_stream_duplex": "readable-stream/duplex",
    "_stream_passthrough": "readable-stream/passthrough",
    "dgram": "react-native-udp",
    "stream": "stream-browserify",
    "timers": "timers-browserify",
    "tty": "tty-browserify",
    "vm": "vm-browserify",
    "tls": false
  }
}
```

Build Gradle

app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation. If none specified and
 *   // "index.android.js" exists, it will be used. Otherwise "index.js" is
 *   // default. Can be overridden with ENTRY_FILE environment variable.
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // https://reactnative.dev/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
 *   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: project(':react-native-config').projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle"
/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here.  If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    lintOptions { 
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        }
    packagingOptions {
            pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
            pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
            pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
            pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
        }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.packageName"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode project.env.get("ANDROID_VERSION_CODE").toInteger() 
        versionName project.env.get("ANDROID_VERSION_NAME")
        missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
           
        }
        release {
           
      }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"
    // implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'    // implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    // implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.2'
      implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar'
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.2.2'
      implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.3.0'
      implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12.+"

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
      exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

 // Google Play services Gradle plugin
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

Answer (score 5):

try looking in your code for like @babel/types; for me, it was to remove `import { exportDefaultSpecifier } from '@babel/types';` then everything was working fine